Windows cmd timeout command not continue
I'm trying to run multiple commands in Windows cmd. And need to sleep for ~4 seconds between the commands.
I copy my commands block to the cmd and then want them to run one after the other with breaks of 4 seconds.
My problem is that the timeout command stops the execution and not continue to the next commands:
python3 my_file.py -a
timeout /t 4 /nobreak > nul
python3 my_file.py -b
timeout /t 4 /nobreak > nul
python3 my_file.py -c

The first and the second lines are running and then it ends and shows the > sign.
(I did the same thing in Linux with the 'sleep' command ant it works perfect)
I also tried different options of the timeout command such as timeout /t 4 and timeout 4 but nothing works...
How can I do it? it must run on Windows cmd and not as batch file.
Thanks
Update:
As @JosefZ answered, my problem caused by the PASTE usage. The timeout command ignored the PASTE command, so I didn't get the next commands.
Using the PING command as his answer solved the issue.

What's your output of where python3? I suspect it's a .bat or .cmd file - then you need to call it.

There is no obvious syntax problem with the timeout commands you have used, although they should more correctly look like this %SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /T 4 /NoBreak 1>NUL.

timeout /? says about the /NOBREAK parameter:

/NOBREAK Ignore key presses and wait specified time.

Ignore, i.e. choke down all content of keyboard buffer filled by a PASTE technique.

A delay can also be produced by the PING command with a
loopback address (127.0.0.1), in tests this consumes less processor
time than Sleep.exe or Timeout.exe. The delay between each ping
is 1 second, so for a delay of 5 seconds ping 6 times.

The following code snippet should work as expected:
python3 my_file.py -a
PING -n 5 127.0.0.1 1>nul 2>&1
python3 my_file.py -b
PING -n 5 127.0.0.1 1>nul 2>&1
python3 my_file.py -c

